# Is this algorithm correct for finding the longest increasing sub-sequence?

Tags: algorithm

I receive a non-sorted array and I need to find the longest increasing sub-sequence. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) the most efficient algorithm is O(nlogn) and this is O(n) so surely I'm doing something stupidly wrong

```
public static int[] longestAscending(int[] arr) {
        // {x /* starting index */, y /* ending index */};
        int[] max = {0, 0};
        int[] current = {0,1};

        for (int i=1; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i-1] < arr[i]) {
                current[1]++;
                if (current[1] - current[0] > max[1] - max[0]) {
                    max[0] = current[0];
                    max[1] = current[1];
                }
            } else {
                current[0] = i;
                current[1] = i + 1;
            }
        }

        return max;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you only comparing two adjacent elements at a time?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem as IVlad stated, you may not only compare adjacent elements. For Searching the longest increasing CONTIGUOUS subsequence you got a pretty decent algorithm there :)

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm only detects contiguous subsequences, not subsequences with gaps. For example:

```
1 9 2 3
```

The longest increasing subsequence here is `1 2 3`, which your algorithm doesn't find.

Comment: Or, as I like to call them, **substrings**. That term shouldn't only apply to sequences of characters.